# SmartTag for adding a "using" statement for extension method

Tags: c#, ide, extension-methods

Lets say I have the following code that needs to be moved to another file/class:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;


    class Class1
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            IEnumerable<int> l = new List<int>();

            if (l.Count() == 0)
            { 
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I move `SomeMethod` to another class (in another file) that does not have (say) a `using System.Linq` declaration, the `l.Count()` statement would not compile giving the very obvious message:

```
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

If the new class/file does not have a `using System.Collections.Generic` declaration and you put your cursor on the `IEnumerable<int>` you will get a SmartTag that would suggest possible using-declarations. If you put your cursor on the `Count()` extension call you get no SmartTag to suggest the `using System.Linq` declaration.

Is there maybe an IDE extension out there that would help add a using statement for extension methods as explained above? This would help allot with refactoring code.

Comment: ReSharper does this, but it's not free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that would be free:
Download and install [DevExpress CodeRush Express](https://go.devexpress.com/CodeRushX.aspx) and then download and install the [CR_ExtensionMethodsHelper community plugin](https://github.com/RoryBecker/CR_ExtensionMethodsHelper/releases/latest).

You could also try the following commercial products (not free):

1. [DevExpress CodeRush](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/CodeRush/) (with [CR_ExtensionMethodsHelper community plugin](https://github.com/RoryBecker/CR_ExtensionMethodsHelper/releases/latest); although there is a [request pending](http://www.devexpress.com/support/center/Question/Details/T116759) to have this plugin supported natively)
2. [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) (I'm not using this one my self, but others have suggested it)